# How do i save integers to msql database in android?

Tags: android, mysql, json, integer, save

experts and gurus.i am working on an android application that takes values using check boxes and then save to mysql database using JSON Parsing.I manage to do it with strings but now i want to save integers i don't know how to do it.this is my code working for saving strings.Can you help me on how to save integers using the same code.
Below is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
CheckBox reading, playing;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//JSON parser class 
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
         private static final String POST_COMMENT_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8081/bfc_webservice/scoring.php";

         private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
         private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    /*
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String hobbies="";
             int firstValue = 0;
             int secondValue = 0;
             int thirdValue = 0;
             int fourthValue = 0;
             int fifthValue = 0;



            if(reading.isChecked())
               firstValue = 10;
            if(playing.isChecked())
                secondValue = 20;
             if(listening.isChecked())
              thirdValue = 30;
             if(singing.isChecked())
              fourthValue = 40;
             if(dancing.isChecked())
              fifthValue = 50;

              textHobbies.setText("Your Hobbies are : " +  firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue + fourthValue) ;

        }
    });
    */


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //final TextView textHobbies = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    /*
     reading=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkReading);
     playing=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkPlay);


    String hobbies="";
    int firstValue = 0;
    int secondValue = 0;



    if(reading.isChecked())
      firstValue = 10;
   if(playing.isChecked())
    secondValue = 20;


     textHobbies.setText("Your Hobbies are : " +  firstValue + secondValue) ;
    */

    new SendComment().execute();
}


class SendComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Adding scores...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int success;

         reading=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkReading);
         playing=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkPlay);


        String hobbies="";
        String firstValue = "";
        String secondValue = "";



        if(reading.isChecked())
          firstValue = "great";
       if(playing.isChecked())
        secondValue = "awesome";


        try{
            //Building parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reading", firstValue));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("playing", secondValue));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting to the script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(POST_COMMENT_URL, "POST", params);

            //full json response
            Log.d("Post comment attempt", json.toString());

            //json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if(success == 1){
                Log.d("Comment Added!", json.toString());
                finish();

                return  json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);


            }else{
                Log.d("Comment Failure", json.toString());
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //dismiss dialog 
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if(file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }



 }
```

}

Here is my JSON Parsing class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
// constructor
```

public JSONParser() {

```
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // defaultHttpClient

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }



    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

    }

   // return JSON String

    return jObj;



}   

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
     public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
          // Making HTTP request
         try {
        // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
              // request method is POST
             // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

               HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
              is = httpEntity.getContent();


             }else if(method == "GET"){
                    // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
               url += "?" + paramString;
               HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
              }          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }


            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                      is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

              sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }


            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error in parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String

        return jObj;
     }
```

}

If anyone help me by modifying my existing code.Thank you in advance.

Comment: the result of JSON is of type `string`. You have to cast it to `int` if you want to use it as an integer..

Answer (score 0):

The way I had implemented this when using different data types when connecting to an SQL database was by converting the data in the PHP script. Take a look the following PHP method convert a string to Double (since I used it for currency values). Make sure that the data type in the table of the database accepts integers too:

```
public function storeNewTicket($userId, $amount) {

        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $issuingDate = strtotime($date);
        $newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $issuingDate);

        $currentBalance = $this->getBalance($userId);
        $floatCurrentBalance = floatval($currentBalance['balance']);
        $floatAmount = (float) $amount;

    $validity = $this->getTicketsForUser($userId);
    $floatValidity = intval($validity['TicketValidity']);

}
```

In the code above I am using both `floatval` and `intval` This depends on whether you want a whole integer value or a decimal one.

Hope this helps :)